# Firefox iframe custom scroll bug

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, iframe, scroll

This is a weird bug but all custom scroll plugins like [nicescroll](http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/) , [perfectscrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) , or even [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) have the same issue , whenever an iframe is embedded with the container to be scrolled , the iframe never listens to mouse wheel event neither touch swipe events ( to scroll on mobile devices ) , searched everywhere to find a solution seems that people have submitted issues on plugins pages , but no one realised that it is a universal bug not a bug from the plugin itself.

Here is the [**bug**](http://codepen.io/prollygeek/pen/RNpbJG) reporduced , should run this on firefox.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="demo">    
    <iframe width="100%" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SyoA4LXQco4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div style="height:800px;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#demo
{
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
$("#demo").niceScroll({
            cursorborder: "0px solid #000",
            horizrailenabled:"false"

                })

alert("run this page on firefox , then try to scroll page ")

})
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I am experiencing the same in some cases of FF.

Comment: @izk yes i made a work around to put layout div , and custom script to correspond to custom events.